# Serving css in express + webpack server

Tags: css, node.js, express, webserver, webpack

I'm really struggling serving a static file in Express + Webpack. 
The file is a plain css stylesheet, but I can't get the html page to load it.

Here's my current configuration:

**server.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
var config = require('./webpack.config')
var express = require('express')

var app = new express()
var port = 3005

var compiler = webpack(config)
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }))
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

// this should tell express that files located under the /public/ folder are static
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("==>  Listening on port %s. Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
})
```

A quite standard **webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
}
```

---

Here's the css inclusion in the index.html file:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
```

I have the `style.css` file located in `public/styles/style.css`, so I should see it, right?

In fact, if I go to `http://localhost:3005/styles/style.css` the file is available and served correctly, however trying to load it through `index.html` does not work. It seems like the network request is never sent.

Any idea on how to fix this? Am I missing something basilar about express/webpack?

I'm also using *react-router*, if this may ever be relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it:

Just installed the appropriate npm packages `css-loader` and `style-loader` and added the appropriate loaders to **webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'styles': path.join(__dirname, 'styles'),
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }, {
      test: /\.css?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ],
      include: __dirname
    }]
  }
}
```

Also worth noting that I moved the css file from `public/styles` to `styles`.

Upon fixing this and adding the appropriate `import 'styles/dashboard.css'` to **index.js** everything works fine now! Loading the file from html `<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">` is useless, since is bundled inside the main javascript file.